# Is there a way to Install Kubernetes offline (without internet connection) on Ubuntu 16.04 machine

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install  Install Kubernetes offline (without an internet connection) on Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Is there any procedure or steps to follow for the installation without internet connectivity?

Answer (score 3):

If you have one machine with no external internet connectivity, then there is no option to install k8s. However if you download all the required software/images you need to install k8s beforehand, then it is possible. Simply transfer the data between machine. Please refer to https://gist.github.com/jgsqware/6595126e17afc6f187666b0296ea0723

Comment: This one is for centos. Is there any procedure for Ubuntu?

Comment: have you tried the preceding steps up until that point?

Comment: Yes I did and I had no success in installing the K8s offline.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through downloading the *apt.kubernetes.io* mirror for Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial).

Use this project to download the mirror : https://github.com/flavienbwk/apt-mirror-docker

And put the following lines to your `mirror.list` file :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial main
```

At this step, you must be running the server provided in the repo.

Append these lines to your client's `/etc/apt/source.list` :

```
deb http://localhost:8080/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://localhost:8080/apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial main
```

Now you can install Kubernetes offline :

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubectl kubeadm kubelet
```